# Configure GlassFish Server to send alert emails

Tags: java, email, glassfish, webserver

Can we configure glassfish_3 to send auto emails on specific type of exceptions/errors for multiple applications deployed on it, in single domain.

Scenario is simple, if applications fails to respond for a request or throws some exception e.g ResourceNotFound, Glassfish should send email to admin with error code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should add your codes @muhammad

Comment: Do you have example code?